# Is there a way to remove imports in JShell?

Tags: java, import, java-9, jshell

I'm discovering JShell and I discovered the imports added in by default:

```
jshell> /imports
|    import java.io.*
|    import java.math.*
|    import java.net.*
|    import java.nio.file.*
|    import java.util.*
|    import java.util.concurrent.*
|    import java.util.function.*
|    import java.util.prefs.*
|    import java.util.regex.*
|    import java.util.stream.*
```

After doing that I added my own import using the following command:

```
import java.lang.Math
```

Is there a way to remove the latter import without killing the active session/restarting?

I've tried to issue the `/edit` command, remove the import, click accept and click exit, but that didn't do the trick.

As stated in the comments, `/reset` removes the import, but it also removes anything else previously input in the session. Is there a specific way to ONLY remove the import statement?

Comment: You can reset state: `/reset`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Indeed, but that also removes every other active stuff.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Reset would not remove default imports. @ Thibstars is that what you intend to do?

Comment: @nullpointer No, I'm just looking to remove the import I added myself. I've added an answer myself now that suits my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some searching, I managed to [find a solution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00). It's a combination of `/list` (to know which line to remove) and `/drop`.

```
/drop [name[ name...]|id[ id...]]
```

> Drops a snippet, making it inactive. Provide either the name or the ID
>   of an import, class, method, or variable. For more than one snippet,
>   *separate the names and IDs with a space*. Use the `/list` command to see
>   the IDs of code snippets.

```
jshell> import java.lang.Math

jshell> /list

   1 : import java.lang.Math;

jshell> /drop 1

jshell> /imports
|    import java.io.*
|    import java.math.*
|    import java.net.*
|    import java.nio.file.*
|    import java.util.*
|    import java.util.concurrent.*
|    import java.util.function.*
|    import java.util.prefs.*
|    import java.util.regex.*
|    import java.util.stream.*
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for a way to auto-import the common libraries:

```
jshell JAVASE
```

That will import ~200 packages automatically. Like we havent't had seen enough of unworldly design decisions in the Java world, a smile may disappear when addressing the first `List`:

```
jshell> List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
|  Error:
|  reference to List is ambiguous
|    both class java.awt.List in java.awt and interface java.util.List in java.util match
|  List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
|  ^--^
|  Error:
|  reference to Duration is ambiguous
|    both class javax.xml.datatype.Duration in javax.xml.datatype and class java.time.Duration in java.time match
|  List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
|       ^------^
```

That can be fixed, but one needs to create a startup script:

1. Start `jshell JAVASE`
2. Show imports: `/imports`
3. Copy that to a file, remove all lines with `java.awt` and other unwanted imports
4. Save these imports to a file `jshell-imports`
5. Start `jshell jshell-imports`

```
jshell> List<Duration> durations = new ArrayList<>();
durations ==> []
```

Of course, the file has to be recreated for each Java update.