# Is there a way to reset default imports of JShell?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

Following the post [Is there a way to remove imports in JShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808748/is-there-a-way-to-remove-imports-in-jshell). I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the default imports as well.

```
jshell> /imports
|    import java.io.*
|    import java.math.*
|    import java.net.*
|    import java.nio.file.*
|    import java.util.*
|    import java.util.concurrent.*
|    import java.util.function.*
|    import java.util.prefs.*
|    import java.util.regex.*
|    import java.util.stream.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default imports from JShell are part of the startup scripts of the JShell. You can follow [JShell documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00) to find the option to avoid loading the startup scripts and can start jshell like this :

```
jshell --no-startup
```

The difference can be seen in the following screenshot:-

[image]